# Proving that $\Sigma \cup \Gamma \models \psi \implies \Sigma \cup \Gamma_0 \models \psi$

Tags: logic

I was reading the solution my teacher suggested for the following problem:

> Show that the set of all infinite totally ordered sets $A$ is not  finitely axiomatizable

The solution goes like this:

---

My teacher defined a set of sentences $\Sigma$ that express the fact that a set is totally ordered, and then defined a set $\Gamma = \{\gamma_1,\gamma_2, ...\}$ where each $\gamma_n$ expresses the fact that the set has at least $n$ elements. So $A=\text{Mod}(\Sigma \cup \Gamma)$.

Then he assumed that $A$ is  finitely axiomatizable, this is: $A=\text{Mod}(\psi)$. He peoved that it implies that $$\Sigma \cup \Gamma \models \psi $$

And then he argued that if follows from the Compactness theorem that there is a finite subset $\Gamma_0\subset \Gamma$ such that: $$\Sigma \cup \Gamma_0 \models \psi$$

---

I don't get how this last step follows from the compactness theorem. In my class this is how the teacher stated the theorem:

> Let $\Sigma \cup \{\phi\} $ be a set of formulas in a first order language $\cal L$. Then:
>
> 1. $\Sigma \models \phi$ iff $\Sigma_0 \models \phi$, for some $\Sigma_0\subseteq \Sigma$ finite
> 2. $\Sigma$ has a model if and only if every finite subset of $\Sigma $ has a model.

I think that my teacher might be using (1), but the thing that bothers me, is that (1) just states "for some $\Sigma_0$", meaning that there is no way to be sure that $\Sigma \cup \Gamma_0 \models \psi$, instead of $\Sigma_0 \cup \Gamma_0 \models \psi$, for some $\Sigma_0 \subset \Sigma$. We can't control what formulas we 'delete' from $\Sigma \cup \Gamma$.

How did my teacher arrive at that conclution?

Comment: If $\Sigma_0\cup\Gamma_0\models\psi$, then $\Sigma\cup\Gamma_0\models\psi$. (More generally, any consequence of a set $H$ of hypotheses is also a consequence of any superset of $H$.)